# How to trigger a loop using onkeydown(once pressed)?

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I'm working on a game I want that when I press the keyboard button once, jump on my gaming character until the given loop condition is incorrect. But now the problem is that my character is jumping as well as pressing the keyboard button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--AnimationUsingKeyboard.html-->
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>AnimationUsingKeyboard.html</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="AnimationUsingKeyboard.js">
            //<![CDATA[
            //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <h1>Animation Using Keyboard Input</h1>
        <div id="outline" style="position:absolute;
                                width:50px;
                                 height:50px;
                                 top:100px;
                                 left:5px;">
            <img id="krizen" src="krizen1.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="krizen.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="output">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var imgList=new Array("krizen1.png",
                      "krizen2.png",
                      "krizen3.png",
                      "krizen4.png",
                      "krizen5.png",
                      "krizen6.png",
                      "krizen7.png",
                      "krizen8.png"
                      );
var outline;
var krizen;
var jump;

function init(){
 outline=document.getElementById("outline");
 krizen=document.getElementById("krizen");
 document.onkeydown=keyListner;
}
function keyListner(e){
 if(!e){
e=window.event;
}//end if
if(e.keyCode==38){
 jump=parseInt(outline.style.top);
 while(jump!=70){
 outline.style.top=jump+"px";
 jump-=5;
 }//end while
}//end if
}//end keyListner function
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Usually user input and loops are not compatible.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: kindly show your html as well buddy.. along with a bit more of the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set a variable; lets say Pressed to 1 if the key is pressed, and if its released it turns Pressed to 0 and the loop checks if Pressed===1

Comment: If u want it to not stop looping u just dont add the Pressed===0 part!

Comment: also use setTimeout to animate the jumping and check if Pressed==1 as well, as doing it in a loop will NOT work

Comment: How do i like comments? @Nikos M. Liked!